# Postgres: Error constraint "fk" of relation "tbl" does not exist (with Yii - PHP)

Tags: postgresql, yii, phpstorm

I searched for this problem. But my postgres user has enough grant and I do not think I have misspelling error. However I am newbie.

I have this error message:

```
21:38:03 set search_path='public'
21:38:03 ALTER TABLE public.tbl_user DROP CONSTRAINT "fk-user-access-user-id"
21:38:03 ERROR: constraint "fk-user-access-user-id" of relation "tbl_user" does not exist
```

I use the PhpStorm. I just open the database view, expanded the `tbl_user` table, right click and select "drop". And I got this error in the console.
So the above SQL command generated by the PhpStorm.

Then I tried with these commands manually on Ubuntu:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_user DROP CONSTRAINT "fk-user-access-user-id"
ALTER TABLE "tbl_user" DROP CONSTRAINT "fk-user-access-user-id"
```

But I get the same error.

In the PhpStorm I see this definition:

```
"fk-user-access-user-id" FOREIGN KEY (access_id) REFERENCES tbl_access (id)
```

The `tbl_access` table exists with the primary id key.

I do not understand this error message, because the `"fk-user-access-user-id"` foreign key is at the `tbl_user` and so for me the `'relation "tbl_user" does not exist'` strange. I do not understand.

I tried to find similar problem on StackOverflow, but I gave up after 20x question reading.

By the way, the postgres code was generated by the Yii framework.

```
$this->addColumn('{{%user}}', 'access_id', $this->integer()->notNull()->defaultValue(1)->after('status'));
$this->addForeignKey('fk-user-access-user-id', '{{%user}}', 'access_id', '{{%access}}', 'id');
```

- first row mean add `access_id` column to the user table.
- second row: create foreign key with 'fk-user...' name on tbl_user table's access_id column references to tbl_access table's id column.

So I used this PHP code to generate this SQL commands. I prefer this way because for me the migration files are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the definition and actual implementation in your underlying DB has changed from what the app has recorded.  Depending on what the history is, either a change in the app for that foreign key relationship was not migrated to persist the change at the database level, or someone has executed some operation directly at the DB level to remove the relationship. You will need to sync up the app layer to the DB at this point I would think.